# Ignore warning and carry on

Tags: php

I am running a script where a url parameter is increasing by 1. Every so often, I get the error message below and the script comes to a halt:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://example.com?id=431): failed to open
>   stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 Please retry after few
>   minutes

```
$i = 1;
while($file = file_get_contents('https://example.com?id='.$i)) {
  echo ''.$i.'</br>';
$i++
}
```

While I know I can use `error_reporting(0);` to stop the warnings from appearing, my question is as follows: will the script continue running after the hidden warning?

Comment: **Ignoring warnings, errors is not a good idea**.

Comment: @ZainFarooq Does that allow the script to continue running or does it just hide the error but still stop the script?

Comment: You could suppress warnings but not recommended `@file_get_contents`. If you still plan to do so I suggest you check if `$file` is `false` or not

Comment: Try adding an @ before file_get_contents. Like @file_get_contents(...)

Comment: @EnesApaydın What will that do?

Comment: It'll pass the errors for this command, and continue running other steps. And also it does not effect any other function to not to display its own errors. Do not use error_reporting, it disables errors for every other functions.

Comment: This won't work, since suppressing the error would still cause `$file` not to be set, thus breaking your `while` loop. You need to try a different approach

Comment: @jurgemaister Are you saying that `@file_get_contents` won't work? Or `error_reporting(0);`? Or both?

Comment: @TheCodesee It will suppress the warning, but your loop will break. Either you have to know the max amount of files you want to retrieve beforehand, or accept that it will break on the first error.

Comment: @jurgemaister you're probably right, so you can do this to avoid this problem Codesee: $data=@file_get_conte‌​nts(...)." "; and you can trim it inside loop if you wish.

Answer (score 5):

You can, of course, disable error reporting as others have suggested. However, there are two MUCH better solutions.

First, you could use `set_error_handler` to create a function which converts errors into exceptions (code in Example 1 here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php). Then, you can simply use a `try` and `catch` to check to see if an exception has occurred, and handle it appropriately. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php

Another solution would be to use PHP's cURL library (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). cURL will let you check if an error has occurred when you make an HTTP request, and you can respond appropriately.

To be clear, since it seems to be OP's only concern: **both of these solutions will allow the script to continue running after an error has occurred.** They also have the added benefit of allowing OP to create code that *makes a predetermined programmatic response to errors* rather than just blindly ignoring any and all errors with unknown results (and no indication that they even happened).

Finally, a note that's applicable to this particular situation: HTTP 429 is "too many requests," which makes sense given that OP is placing these requests one after another with no delay. Sleeping (http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) between HTTP requests would likely eliminate the problem entirely.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something you should use in prod, but try:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

I think it is better to check if the file is reachable before trying to read it.

Comment: Does that allow the script to continue running or does it just hide the error but still stop the script?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the condition, e.g.:

```
while($i < 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of the script to avoid the **warnings** and **notices**.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

> This will still show Fatal run-time errors. These indicate errors that
>   can not be recovered from, such as a memory allocation problem.
>   Execution of the script is halted.

To turn of all the errors and warning,

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: Does that allow the script to continue running or does it just hide the error but still stop the script?

Comment: Yeah that would allow script to run unless you got any fatal run-time errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Put this at the top of script

Comment: Does that allow the script to continue running or does it just hide the error but still stop the script?

Comment: If your contents are not reachable then probably it just stop reporting errors.

Comment: But will the url parameter continue increasing?